# XCOPY and RENAME batch file?

Tags: windows, copy, rename, move, xcopy

I need to move a directory recursively to a new location, and rename the directory. Do I just use XCOPY to move the directory, then run the RENAME command on it (or vice versa) or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `xcopy /E sourcefolder destinationfolder\newname\`. If the folder "newname" does not exist yet, the trailing backslash suppresses the question whether you mean a file a directory. Answering file is not what you want.